# Unresolved reference: firebasemessaging

Tags: flutter, dart

Getting this error i have try to fixed this ref:[Application.kt: Unresolved reference: firebasemessaging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65408738/application-kt-unresolved-reference-firebasemessaging) but didnt work so i need to posted again i also tried to delete the application.kt file but didnt work. If anyone know the solution please let me know what i am doing wrong so i can learn to not repeat these again

```
 ext.kotlin_version = '1.4.32'
    dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.4'
            classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
            classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        }




package com.godatu.dance

import io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication
import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry
import io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FlutterFirebaseMessagingService

class Application : FlutterApplication(), PluginRegistry.PluginRegistrantCallback {

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        FlutterFirebaseMessagingService.setPluginRegistrant(this)
    }

    override fun registerWith(registry: PluginRegistry?) {
        if (registry != null) {
            FirebaseCloudMessagingPluginRegistrant.registerWith(registry)
            FlutterLocalNotificationPluginRegistrant.registerWith(registry)
            FlutterPathProviderPluginRegistrant.registerWith(registry)
        }
    }

}


enter code here
   [   +2 ms] e: C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Android\godatu-App\android\app\src\main\kotlin\com\godatu\dance\Application.kt: (6, 27): Unresolved reference: firebasemessaging
    [   +3 ms] e: C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Android\godatu-App\android\app\src\main\kotlin\com\godatu\dance\Application.kt: (7, 27): Unresolved reference: firebasemessaging
    [        ] e: C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Android\godatu-App\android\app\src\main\kotlin\com\godatu\dance\Application.kt: (12, 9): Unresolved reference: FlutterFirebaseMessagingService
    [        ] e: C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Android\godatu-App\android\app\src\main\kotlin\com\godatu\dance\Application.kt: (20, 7): Redeclaration: FirebaseCloudMessagingPluginRegistrant
    [        ] e: C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Android\godatu-App\android\app\src\main\kotlin\com\godatu\dance\Application.kt: (26, 13): Unresolved reference: FirebaseMessagingPlugin
    [        ] e: C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Android\godatu-App\android\app\src\main\kotlin\com\godatu\dance\FirebaseCloudMessagingPluginRegistrant.kt: (5, 27): Unresolved reference: firebasemessaging
    [        ] e: C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Android\godatu-App\android\app\src\main\kotlin\com\godatu\dance\FirebaseCloudMessagingPluginRegistrant.kt: (8, 7): Redeclaration: FirebaseCloudMessagingPluginRegistrant
    [        ] e: C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Android\godatu-App\android\app\src\main\kotlin\com\godatu\dance\FirebaseCloudMessagingPluginRegistrant.kt: (17, 17): Unresolved reference: FirebaseMessagingPlugin
    [  +84 ms] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
    [        ] * What went wrong:
    [        ] Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'.
    [        ] > Compilation error. See log for more details
    [        ] * Try:
    [        ] Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
    [        ] * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
    [        ] BUILD FAILED in 27s
    [        ] 399 actionable tasks: 5 executed, 394 up-to-date
    [{"event":"app.progress","params":{"appId":"82f5465d-087d-4b13-8c4a-7ae1698e399b","id":"0","progressId":null,"finished":true}}]
    [+5408 ms] Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
    [   +4 ms] 
               #0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:10:3)
               #1      RunCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/run.dart:550:9)
               <asynchronous suspension>
               #2      FlutterCommand.verifyThenRunCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:1157:12)
               <asynchronous suspension>
               #3      FlutterCommand.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:1009:27)
               <asynchronous suspension>
               #4      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
               <asynchronous suspension>
               #5      AppContext.run (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:149:12)
               <asynchronous suspension>
               #6      CommandRunner.runCommand (package:args/command_runner.dart:197:13)
               <asynchronous suspension>
               #7      FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:278:9)
               <asynchronous suspension>
               #8      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
               <asynchronous suspension>
               #9      AppContext.run (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:149:12)
               <asynchronous suspension>
               #10     FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:234:5)
               <asynchronous suspension>
               #11     run.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:64:9)
               <asynchronous suspension>
               #12     run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:62:12)
               <asynchronous suspension>
               #13     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
               <asynchronous suspension>
               #14     AppContext.run (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:149:12)
               <asynchronous suspension>
               #15     runInContext (package:flutter_tools/src/context_runner.dart:73:10)
               <asynchronous suspension>
               #16     main (package:flutter_tools/executable.dart:90:3)
               <asynchronous suspension>
    
    
    [{"event":"app.stop","params":{"appId":"82f5465d-087d-4b13-8c4a-7ae1698e399b"}}]
    [  +18 ms] "flutter run" took 36,338ms.
    [{"id":0,"error":"app '82f5465d-087d-4b13-8c4a-7ae1698e399b' not found","trace":"#0      AppDomain.stop (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/daemon.dart:698:7)\n#1      Domain.handleCommand.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/daemon.dart:217:34)\n#2      new Future.sync (dart:async/future.dart:218:31)\n#3      Domain.handleCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/daemon.dart:215:5)\n#4      Daemon._handleRequest (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/daemon.dart:141:28)\n#5      _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1362:47)\n#6      _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1265:19)\n#7      _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1170:7)\n#8      _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:341:11)\n#9      _BufferingStreamSubscription._add (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:271:7)\n#10     _ForwardingStreamSubscription._add (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:123:11)\n#11     _MapStream._handleData (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:218:10)\n#12     _ForwardingStreamSubscription._handleData (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:153:13)\n#13     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1362:47)\n#14     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1265:19)\n#15     _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1170:7)\n#16     _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:341:11)\n#17     _BufferingStreamSubscription._add (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:271:7)\n#18     _ForwardingStreamSubscription._add (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:123:11)\n#19     _WhereStream._handleData (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:195:12)\n#20     _ForwardingStreamSubscription._handleData (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:153:13)\n#21     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1362:47)\n#22     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1265:19)\n#23     _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1170:7)\n#24     _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:341:11)\n#25     _BufferingStreamSubscription._add (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:271:7)\n#26     _SinkTransformerStreamSubscription._add (dart:async/stream_transformers.dart:63:11)\n#27     _EventSinkWrapper.add (dart:async/stream_transformers.dart:13:11)\n#28     _StringAdapterSink.add (dart:convert/string_conversion.dart:238:11)\n#29     _LineSplitterSink._addLines (dart:convert/line_splitter.dart:155:13)\n#30     _LineSplitterSink.addSlice (dart:convert/line_splitter.dart:130:5)\n#31     StringConversionSinkMixin.add (dart:convert/string_conversion.dart:163:5)\n#32     _SinkTransformerStreamSubscription._handleData (dart:async/stream_transformers.dart:111:24)\n#33     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1362:47)\n#34     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1265:19)\n#35     _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1170:7)\n#36     _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:341:11)\n#37     _BufferingStreamSubscription._add (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:271:7)\n#38     _SinkTransformerStreamSubscription._add (dart:async/stream_transformers.dart:63:11)\n#39     _EventSinkWrapper.add (dart:async/stream_transformers.dart:13:11)\n#40     _StringAdapterSink.add (dart:convert/string_conversion.dart:238:11)\n#41     _StringAdapterSink.addSlice (dart:convert/string_conversion.dart:243:7)\n#42     _Utf8ConversionSink.addSlice (dart:convert/string_conversion.dart:317:20)\n#43     _Utf8ConversionSink.add (dart:convert/string_conversion.dart:310:5)\n#44     _ConverterStreamEventSink.add (dart:convert/chunked_conversion.dart:72:18)\n#45     _SinkTransformerStreamSubscription._handleData (dart:async/stream_transformers.dart:111:24)\n#46     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1362:47)\n#47     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1265:19)\n#48     _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1170:7)\n#49     _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:341:11)\n#50     _BufferingStreamSubscription._add (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:271:7)\n#51     _SyncStreamControllerDispatch._sendData (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:733:19)\n#52     _StreamController._add (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:607:7)\n#53     _StreamController.add (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:554:5)\n#54     _Socket._onData (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:2144:41)\n#55     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1370:13)\n#56     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1265:19)\n#57     _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1170:7)\n#58     _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:341:11)\n#59     _BufferingStreamSubscription._add (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:271:7)\n#60     _SyncStreamControllerDispatch._sendData (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:733:19)\n#61     _StreamController._add (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:607:7)\n#62     _StreamController.add (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:554:5)\n#63     new _RawSocket.<anonymous closure> (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:1680:33)\n#64     _NativeSocket.issueReadEvent.issue (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:1192:14)\n#65     _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:40:21)\n#66     _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:49:5)\n#67     _runPendingImmediateCallback (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:120:13)\n#68     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:185:5)\n"}]
```

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to take care of registrant in flutter v2. It will automatically handles it by itself. Hence you don't need to include Application class.

Comment: works... i deleted the Application.kt and remove the reference in the manifest.xml ( android:name=".Application")

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing you're on an older version of Firebase core and messaging and any other firebase plugins you have. I just went through a bunch of similar headaches, tried all those solutions, went through a bunch of github threads, nothing worked.

What did work, was forcing myself to upgrade to null safety just so I could use all the up to date firebase plugins. After that, FCM works like a charm and you don't have to touch your Kotlin/Java file.

When I first tried to implement FCM, I had ended up with a chain of firebase dependency conflicts with firebase storage/analytics etc...that wasn't resolved until I was down to versions 1-2 years old on some of those plugins.

Now with all these current versions

```
  firebase_analytics: ^8.0.0
  firebase_core: ^1.0.3
  firebase_messaging: ^9.1.1
  firebase_storage: ^8.0.3
```

My Kotlin file is untouched and background notifications don't crash my app.

So it may not be the answer you're looking for, and perhaps not all your dependencies have upgraded to null safety and you can't upgrade anyway, but it's something to consider.

Because if you do upgrade to all the current versions (and Android Embedding if your app is still on V1), then you just follow the [FlutterFire FCM Guide](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/overview) and it all just works with very minimal setup.

It appears the Google team did a lot of work to make it a smoother process because people were justifiably pissed off that it was such a messy process getting 2 Google products to play nicely together.